# How to make a curve at intersection point on a rectangle in css?

Tags: css, geometry, css-shapes, curve

I want to create the following shape:

[image]

Important: If I use "Border Radius" it works on edges, but I require a curve at the intersection (and I do not want this result):

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use some pseudo elements to 'cut in' to the container.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: dimgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.cont:before,
.cont:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
}

.cont:before {
  top: 25%;
}

.cont:after {
  bottom: 25%;
}

.spoke {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #222;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.spoke:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="spoke"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could just keep the container as is and just add a border to your 'spoke':

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: dimgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #222;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 25%;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #222;
  top: calc(25% + 18px);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```